# Ignore Validation on JSF Button Click

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

I have a reset button, and when clicked it would cause the f:converter and f:validate to get triggered which made so sense since it is meant to clear fields.

I was reading [this article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/jsf-and-immediate-attribute-command.html) and it demonstrated how to keep the validation from appearing when I click on my "Reset" button using the `immediate="true"` and this worked great... for only the first reset button.

However, I have multiple reset buttons and set all them to have attribute `immediate="true"` and yet it only seems to work on the first reset button, I still get the error message displaying for invalid data for the other 3 reset buttons.

In case background on layout is needed my XHTML looks something like this:

```
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
    <h:messages globalOnly="true" showDetail="false" infoClass="info" warnClass="warning" errorClass="error" fatalClass="fatal" />
        <h:message for="field1" errorClass="error"></h:message>
        <h:message for="field2" errorClass="error"></h:message>
        <h:message for="field3" errorClass="error"></h:message>
        <h:message for="field4" errorClass="error"></h:message> 
</a4j:outputPanel>
<h:form id="form1" rendered="true">
    <h:panelGrid columns="8">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.label}" />
        <h:inputText id="field1" size="18" maxlength="18" immediate="true"
            value="#{myBean.myField1}">
            <f:converter converterId="LongConverter" />
            <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="18"></f:validateLength>
        </h:inputText>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton id="reset1" type="submit" value="#{bundle.label}" onclick="resetField()"
        styleClass="button" action="#{myBean.reset1}" immediate="true" />
</h:form>
<h:form id="form2" rendered="true">
    <h:panelGrid columns="8">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.label}" />
        <h:inputText id="field2" size="18" maxlength="18" immediate="true"
            value="#{myBean.myField2}">
            <f:converter converterId="LongConverter" />
            <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="18"></f:validateLength>
        </h:inputText>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton id="reset2" type="submit" value="#{bundle.label}" onclick="resetField()"
        styleClass="button" action="#{myBean.reset2}" immediate="true" />
</h:form>
<h:form id="form3" rendered="true">
    <h:panelGrid columns="8">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.label}" />
        <h:inputText id="field3" size="18" maxlength="18" immediate="true"
            value="#{myBean.myField3}">
            <f:converter converterId="LongConverter" />
            <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="18"></f:validateLength>
        </h:inputText>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton id="reset3" type="submit" value="#{bundle.label}" onclick="resetField()"
        styleClass="button" action="#{myBean.reset3}" immediate="true" />
</h:form>
<h:form id="form4" rendered="true">
    <h:panelGrid columns="8">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.label}" />
        <h:inputText id="field4" size="18" maxlength="18" immediate="true"
            value="#{myBean.myField4}">
            <f:converter converterId="LongConverter" />
            <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="18"></f:validateLength>
        </h:inputText>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton id="reset4" type="submit" value="#{bundle.label}" onclick="resetField()"
        styleClass="button" action="#{myBean.reset4}" immediate="true" />
</h:form>
```

I really don't know if the issue is with the button or the ajax being shared by multiple forms?  Can someone tell me the proper way to do this when there are multiple reset buttons / fields like above?

**Edit:**
I tried removing all the immediate=true from the Reset buttons, and of course the error messsage now displays when clicking Reset button.  But I noticed that it only does it on the last three forms reset buttons, not on the first...?

I am hoping this gives more insight to someone that knows what is causing this

Comment: What is the goal of type="submit"?

Comment: @Tires I assume it is needed to call the backing bean myBean.methodName for the action="" attribute?  Feel free to correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I tried removing all the immediate=true from the Reset buttons, and of course the error messsage now displays when clicking Reset button. But I noticed that it only does it on the last three forms reset buttons, not on the first...

Comment: Ideally, your reset button should be of `type="reset"`. The way it is now, the entire enclosing form still gets submitted *and* validated

Comment: @Kairan Guess type="..." could change submit behavior in a non JSF way, that causes trouble. I would suggest to either use pure JSF elements or pure HTML self implemented lifecycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `immediate="true"` on the inputs fields, that makes them being processed as well.

Comment: I have tried removed the  immediate="true" from all the input text boxes and it does solve the issue with the error message appearing when it shouldn't, but now it will not clear the input text box values?

Comment: I tried removing all the immediate=true from the Reset buttons, and of course the error messsage now displays when clicking Reset button. But I noticed that it only does it on the last three forms reset buttons, not on the first...